# Where do I need to place the routing for a (post) function in nodejs with express application?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have made a few websites with Pug in a Nodejs with express application.
On the websites there is also a contact form which people can fill in to ask questions.

My question is; where do I need to place the routing for the mail function?
Let's say that there is only a console.log(123) in that function to keep it easy?!

See below the structure (of the most necessary files):

```
- site
  - config
      - assets
          default.js
          development.js
      - env
          default.js
          development.js
      - lib
          app.js
          express.js
          logger.js
          pug-routes.js
          socket.io.js
      config.js
  - modules
      - core
          - client
              - app
                  config.js
                  init.js
              - config
                  core.client.route-filter.js
                  core.client.routes.js
                  core-admin.client.routes.js
              - controllers
                  header.client.controller.js
                  home.client.controller.js
              - css
              - directives
              - services
              - views
          - server
              - controllers
                  core.server.controller.js
              - routes
                  core.server.routes.js
              - views
                  layout.server.view.html
      - website
          - client
              - css
              - img
              - js   
          - server
              contact.pug
  - node_modules
  - public
  - scripts
  package.json
  server.js
```

Server.js:

```
/* eslint no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs: "error" */
/* eslint indent: ["error", 4] */
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('./config/lib/app');
var server = app.start();

module.exports = app;
```

App.js

```
/* eslint no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs: "error" */
/* eslint indent: ["error", 4] */
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var config = require('../config'),
    mongoose = require('./mongoose'),
    express = require('./express'),
    chalk = require('chalk'),
    seed = require('./seed'),
    Mollie = require('mollie-api-node');

function seedDB() {
    if (config.seedDB && config.seedDB.seed) {
        console.log(chalk.bold.red('Warning:  Database seeding is turned on'));
        seed.start();
    }
}

// Initialize Models
mongoose.loadModels(seedDB);

module.exports.init = function init(callback) {
    mongoose.connect(function (db) {
        // Initialize express
        var app = express.init(db);
        if (callback) callback(app, db, config);
    });
};

module.exports.start = function start(callback) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.init(function (app, db, config) {
        // Start the app by listening on <port> at <host>
        app.listen(config.port, config.host, function () {
            // Create server URL
            const proto = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'secure' ? 'https' : 'http';
            var server = `${proto}://${config.host}:${config.port}`;

            // Logging initialization
            console.log('--');
            console.log(chalk.green(config.app.title));
            console.log();
            console.log(chalk.green('Environment:     ' + process.env.NODE_ENV));
            console.log(chalk.green('Server:          ' + server));
            console.log(chalk.green('Database:        ' + config.db.uri));
            console.log(chalk.green('App version:     ' + config.meanjs.version));
            if (config.meanjs['meanjs-version']) {
                console.log(chalk.green('MEAN.JS version: '
                                        + config.meanjs['meanjs-version']));
            }
            console.log('--');

            if (callback) callback(app, db, config);
        });
    });
};
```

Contact form:

```
form(method="POST" action="/mail")
        case (type)
            when 'slider'
                block
                .row
                    .col-md-8
                        .QapTcha
                            .bgSlider
                                .Slider.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle.e-resize.absolute
                                    .text-center.text-white(style='cursor:e-resize')
                                        i.fa.fa-chevron-right.btn-m-t-QapTcha.align-middle
                        input.d-none.submit(type='submit' name='submit' id=options.id submit=options.submit load=options.load)
                        div(style='fonts-size:11px')!=options.text
            when 'button'
                .row
                    .col-sm-12
                        .panel.panel-info
                            .panel-body
                                block
                .panel-footer
                    .form-group
                        button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block.submit(id=options.inputId submit=options.submit load=options.load type='submit')!=options.text
            default
                +createForm(options, 'slider')
        .feedback
```

I am familiar with node/pug/express, but i am not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in `init()` function of App.js,

```
// Initialize express
var app = express.init(db);

app.post('/mail', (req, res) => {
    // Do your stuff
})
```

Just make sure you add this before starting app.